# Load numpy arrays from compressed bytes

Tags: python, numpy, save, load, bytesio

I'm trying to save (using `savez_compressed`) a bunch of numpy arrays into a `BytesIO` object and then load them back to a variable. So far, I can save the array's using following code

```
# Arrays
a = numpy.random.uniform(size=(10,10)) # dtype is float64
b = numpy.random.uniform(size=(10,10)) # dtype is float64

# Create bytes object
buf = io.BytesIO()

# Save the arrays into the buffer
numpy.savez_compressed(buf, a=a, b=b)

# Closed the buffer
buf.close()
```

I've been trying different methods to load them back. For example

`ab = numpy.frombuffer(buf.read(), dtype='float64')`

which raises `ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size`. And trying to load as one would if it was a file

`ab = numpy.load(buf)`

raises `ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False` and when `buf.read()` i get `ValueError: embedded null byte`.

Comment: Btw. To close the buffer, you sould use `buf.close()`, and not `buf.seek()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me [`Numpy version: numpy==1.16.1`]:

```
import numpy
import io

# Arrays
a = numpy.random.uniform(size=(10,10)) # dtype is float64
b = numpy.random.uniform(size=(10,10)) # dtype is float64

# Create bytes object
buf = io.BytesIO()

# Save the arrays into the buffer
numpy.savez_compressed(buf, a=a, b=b)
buf.seek(0)

ab = numpy.load(buf)
print(ab['a'])
print(ab['b'])

# Closed the buffer
buf.close()
```

Comment: It works!! Although, it doesn't work with my original arrays but they are of dtype "O". I guess that's the problem...

Comment: It was the dtype. Thanks!!